# E: The package ttf-mscorefonts-installer needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it

Tags: ubuntu-22.04

tit@HP-EliteBook-840-G3:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install code_1.70.2-1660629410_amd64.deb
[sudo] password for tit:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
**E: The package ttf-mscorefonts-installer needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it**

tit@HP-EliteBook-840-G3:~$ sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
**E: The package ttf-mscorefonts-installer needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.**

Answer (score 0):

go to this path: /var/lib/dpkg
there would be a text file named status.
open status file by an editor with superuser privileges and search for the "ttf-mscorefonts-installer" in the status file, then delete the related lines, save the file and exit.
I had the same problem as you and this worked for me.